# Makefile 'missing separator' for ifneq

Tags: makefile

I know there are other issues with similar titles, but they don't seem to hold the solution.

Heres my makefile:

```
# Compiler Command
CC = mpiCC
CFLAGS = -c -I./header

# collecting object file names
src = $(wildcard source/*.cpp)
src1 = $(src:.cpp=.o)

objects := $(src1:source/%=bin/%)

# Compile object files into binary
all : $(objects)
    $(CC) -o run $(objects)
ifneq($(n),)                         // <- error location , line 15
    mpirun -np $(n) run
endif

# Generate object files by compiling .cpp and .h files
bin/%.o : source/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $?
    mv *.o bin

# Clean Recipe
.PHONY : clean
clean : 
    rm -rf all $(objects)
```

The goal of the ifneq is to have the binary run whenever it finishes compiling.
for example, a user runs the command:

`make` <- builds without running

`make n=5` <- builds and runs on 5 processes

Whenever I use either of these, I get the error:
`makefile:15: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

I've used cat -e -t -v to verify everything is tabbed instead of spaced. according to (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Example) this conditional should function.

Comment: You must have a space between `ifneq` and its argument.  You can't run them together.

Comment: dang, should have seen that. 
Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You could have [pared this down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to half a dozen lines that still reproduced the error. And with a working example of `ineq` from the documentation, you could have pasted together a working makefile that did everything your failing makefile tried to do. And you could have edited these two toward each other until there was literally no difference except that space.

Answer (score 0):

@MadScientist solved it. You need to put a space in between ifneq and its argument. For example:

`ifneq($(n),0)` is invalid.
`ifneq ($(n),0)` is valid.